# Insert Point (Geometry) value in PostgreSQL with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgis, postgresql-9.1

Please give me code example to insert records containing SQL statement:

```
insert into TABLE 
(id, value1, value2, point, value3) 
values
(1,'A', 'M', POINT (13.45646, 56.61782),5);
```

in JDBC/Postgresql code.

If anyone has solution of `PreparedStatement` or anyother useful solution it is highly welcomed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the simplest level, you can build a prepared statement using [geometry constructors](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors) to pass parameters.

```
insert into "TABLE"(id, value1, value2, point, value3)
values(1, $1, $2, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($3, $4), 4326)), $5);
```

Where `$3` and `$4` are the longitude and latitude.

---

See also the [PostGIS documentation for the JDBC interface](https://postgis.net/docs/ch06.html#idm2966) which may be useful with other geometry types (LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon).